# c++ Read from file get struct enum value

Tags: c++

```
enum Person {Person1Name, Person2Name, Person3Name};

struct MyInfo
{
  Person person ;
}
```

Let say the person type his name "John", and I 
    infile >> (what should i write here to read what the user type for his name and associate with enum Person2Name);

Comment: Why `enum`? Don't you want a `vector<Person>`? What's the meaning of `MyInfo`?

Comment: What specifically do you want to do with files? The way you describe the problem, it looks like you need to read some standard input, not from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to really understand what you need, but reading strings and converting them to enum value can be done by explicit ifs

```
std::ifstream in(...);
std::string name;
in >> name;
MyInfo info;
if (name == "John")
   info.person = Person2Name;
```

or some maps

```
std::map<std::string, Person> map;
map["John"] = Person2Name;
in >> name;
info.person = map[name]; // UGLY! not checking if name is in map (use std::map::find in real code)
```

Still it's strange to hardcode all available names as enum in code.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, enums are only implicitly convertible to an `int` type; it makes no sense to associate a `const char*` or `std::string` type like "John". Moreover, enumerated types are supposed to represent a collection of predefined values instead of runtime values like so:

```
enum Colors { BLUE, RED, GREEN };
```

or with C++11:

```
enum class Colors { BLUE, RED, GREEN };
```

Your class should be holding a std::string type variable to store a name read from a file since it is more intuitive for a name to be a std::string type rather than a predefined value.

If we can assume your file looks like so:

```
John
Mary
Joseph
Karen
```

you can write code like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct MyInfo{
    std::string name;
    MyInfo(const std::string& s) : name(s) {}
    MyInfo() {}
};

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  ifstream file("myfile.txt");
  string line;

  if (!file){
     // handle error
     return;
  }

   while (file){
      getline(file, line);
      MyInfo m(line); // this is your MyInfo object
      // ...
   }
}
```